# Inflate output to file performance improvement

Tags: java, compression, inflate

I am following code similar to below. Looking around at different implementations it seems that most people are performing the same operations by doing the byte copy. Is there possible a faster way to handle inflating from a file and printing back out to file?

```
public static String unzipString(InputStream in) {
try {
    int length = (int) in.readUBits( 16 );
    // Add extra byte to array when Inflater is set to true
    byte[] data = in.read( length );

    ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
    InflaterInputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(bin);
    FileoutputStream bout = new FileoutputStream(this.file);
    int b;
    while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
        bout.write(b);
    }
    bout.close();

} catch (IOException io) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Your code looks awkward. I wonder if it will ever compile.

Comment: It is not my code. It is an example that I pulled from a google. It is similar to above given the output writing by byte. My files are large and seems to take a 2 minutes per file to write where each file compressed is 1600KB and uncompressed is 26MB. Outputstream writing the bytes seems to be the long pole in the tent.

Comment: That code is more than awful. You should try another example. I can't improve an already collapsed house.

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a way a simple solution using Inflate to inflate a deflated file without requiring a manual byte copy?

Comment: I guess not. As long as it's pure Java, you have to do byte copy. Even if it appears to avoid direct byte copy, it actually use it somewhere you didn't notice. The only improvement about this is to use buffers to copy multiple, often in the size of several kilo, bytes instead of copying one a time

Comment: Yes I agree but, it could be more future proof if the function doesn't get deprecated. It also fits within my lazy style. :p

Comment: Have you profiled the code?

Answer (score 1):

copying one byte at a time is always going to be a very slow way to process a file. I suggest you use a buffer of say 8 KB instead.

```
try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(this.file)) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
    for (int len; (len = in.read(bytes)) != -1;)
        fout.write(b, 0, len);
}
```

BTW To make it faster you could avoid copying the byte[] in the first place with InputStream which wraps `in` but reads exactly `length` bytes.